gdm3 settings login-screen | Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm using the latest version of Linux Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. The settings for resolution, scaling, and framerate, as well as possibly others, do not work at system startup in the login menu. I want the settings in the login menu to be the same as the settings on my profile. I looked up information about gdm3 and tried to solve the problem, but it didn’t work. Maybe I’m doing something wrong. If so, I would appreciate help or an alternative solution to this problem.
I tried using the gdm-settings application without success, as after applying the settings, the program would freeze and close.
